# Dependencies in the project

Tags: .net-core

I have .NET Core Web API project. In this project i have 5 other project(.Net Core Library Class):

- CarMechanic.Core
- CarMechanic.Resources
- CarMechanic.Model
- CarMechanic.Service
- CarMechanic.Repository

My problem is that from the project CarMechanic.Model I can see the enum which is in the project CarMechanic.Core, unfortunately in the project CarMachanic.Core I do not see the models that are in the project CarMachanic.Model

CarMechanic.Model dependency
[image]

CarMechanic.Core dependency
[image]

When i have checked CarMechanic.Model in dependency then i have error:

> This dependency can not be added because it will create a cyclic
>   relationship

Screen in my AutoMapperProfile where i need import Car model from CarMechanic.Model
[image]

I don't have any idea what is wrong and why CarMechanic.Model see enum from CarMechanic.Core, but CarMechanic.Core don't see model from other solution.  I spent 4-5 hours looking for a solution and I still did not find it.

My repository with this app: https://github.com/PawelCyrklaf/car-mechanic-api

Comment: Error message is pretty clear "cyclic relationship" - you are not allowed to create cyclic relationships between projects. You can have two options 1. since both projects depend on each other - combine them into one project. 2.Introduce third project which will depend on both

Comment: @Fabio I have removed the Core project, and the enum and automapper profiles have moved the model to the project, because here will be the most needed enumas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a seperate "Enums" project for exactly this purpose. They're typically used by the Entities and Models, so need to be seperate to avoid the cyclic relationship problem you're getting

Comment: Is it then that the removal of the Core project and adding the enum and AutoMapperProfile to the model design is a good solution?

Comment: I think it’s the only solution to be able to avoid your circular reference issue.. Things that are shared need to go in separate libraries..